# Intercepting Django fields access

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-descriptors

I understand that Django fields are Python descriptors. Is it possible that I do something extra when I access the field of a Django model? For example, articleInstsnce.author normally returns an `Author` object, can I also make Django print a log during the access?